# Comment Building Blocks

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

These replies are stock for copy/pasting.  Please feel free to add and edit comments.

## Welcome

```
Hello and welcome to Music.SE!  
You can click [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
to see our scope (what/what not to ask) and how to ask questions 
[here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
```

---

## Off- Topic

```
Unfortunately, this question doesn't fit in the scope of this site 
because song key identification is generally not applicable to other people.  Try (this)[http://www.songkeyfinder.com/] website or search "song key" in Google.
```

```
Unfortunately, this question doesn't fit in the scope of our site 
because all questions should be answerable in a non- subjective way.  
You can go [here] (http://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to 
see if there is a way you can edit this question.
```

```
 Hello [name] and welcome to Music P&T. I think your question is 
 a duplicate of the question found (here)[Question link]. and I 
 suggest you check it out and see if it answers your question.
```

```
Welcome to the site! Unfortunately on StackExchange we  are looking
for specific questions that can be answered completely,  rather than
suggestions or recommendations. Take a look at
music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
```

Comment: @JacobSwanson I just broke it into separate lines with 4 spaces at the start of each one. I used the html entity &nbsp; to force paragraph breaks.

Comment: There's also a plugin to do auto comments where someone can add these templates to: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se/4241#4241